# Reading date in proper format

Tags: pandas

I have some issue in reading a column in date format
I have a col_1 and I want an output as per date column

```
col_1          date
10.02.2019     2019-02-10
25.01.2003     2003-01-25
10             nan
00.00.0000     nan
25.2003        nan
02.01.2009     2009-01-02
```

Comment: have you tried something?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) with `errors='coerce'`:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['col_1'], errors='coerce')
print (df)
        col_1       date
0  10.02.2019 2019-10-02
1  25.01.2003 2003-01-25
2          10        NaT
3  00.00.0000        NaT
4     25.2003        NaT
5  02.01.2009 2009-02-01
```

For improve performance use parameter `format` - if need datetimes only by format `DD.MM.YYYY`:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['col_1'], errors='coerce', format='%d.%m.%Y')
print (df)
        col_1       date
0  10.02.2019 2019-02-10
1  25.01.2003 2003-01-25
2          10        NaT
3  00.00.0000        NaT
4     25.2003        NaT
5  02.01.2009 2009-01-02
```